# How to compare key values in java Set

Tags: java, set

I am trying to find the best way to sort these two sets. I  am trying to use the `clientName` property from Set 1 and the `name` property from Set 2 to create a list of names.

The cases that I'm trying to produce are

1. get a list of names that match between set 1 and set 2.
2. get a list of names that do not match between set 2 and set 1.

Set 1

```
[
  BaseAdapter.CreateClient(clientName=jon smith, email=email@email.com, location=null, isCompliant=null), 
  BaseAdapter.CreateClient(clientName=jane doe, email=email@email.com, location=null, isCompliant=null)
]
```

Set 2

```
[Endpoint(id=id1, name=jon smith), Endpoint(id=id2, name=jon doe)]
```

If I just use the intersection of the sets I would end up with `(jon doe, jane doe)`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you only need a list of names for each case, why do you want to sort the sets?  Why not just create two `Set<String>` objects?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you want to do. In your title, it states you want to compare keys and values (of a map)?. Then you always talk about a set (which doesn't have key + values, but entries). In the first part you want to sort 2 sets, in the second part you want to extract information about both sets? What do you want to do?

Comment: That is a good question, I'd like to perform an operation on the outputs separately. So,  
for the names in Set 1 that are not in Set 2, apply operation remove to the output. 

for the names in Set 2 that are not in Set 1, apply operation create to the output.

for the names in Set 2 that are in Set 1, apply operation update to the output. 

Does this make more sense?

Comment: I understand the cases you’ve presented.  They only involve names, so why do you need to sort anything?  Just extract the names from each data set, and use [retainAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) to find the intersection.

Comment: @VGR Nice suggestion, I tried using retainAll, but that just gives me whats common between the two sets. Perhaps, there is a method the will give me the left outer join of Set 1 and Set 2. Then I need the right outer join of Set 1 and Set 2.

Comment: Create a union using [addAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)), then subtract the intersection from the union using [removeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)).

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Person implements Comparable<Person>{
 private int id;
 private String name;

@Override
public int compareTo(Person p){
  return name.compareTo(p.getName());
}

public void setName(String newName){
  name = newName;
}

public void setId(int newId){
  id = newId;
}

public String getName(){
 return name;
}

public String toString(){
 return "Id: " + id + "\nName: " + name + "\n";
}
}
```

and

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{

 public static void main(String arg[]){
  Set<Person> group1 = new TreeSet<Person>();
  
  Person p1 = new Person();
  p1.setId(1);
  p1.setName("Jonh");
  
  Person p2 = new Person();
  p2.setId(2);
  p2.setName("Frank");
  
  group1.add(p1);
  group1.add(p2);
  
  Set<Person> group2 = new TreeSet<Person>();
  
  Person p3 = new Person();
  p3.setId(1);
  p3.setName("Kathy");
  
  Person p4 = new Person();
  p4.setId(2);
  p4.setName("Jonh");
  
  group2.add(p3);
  group2.add(p4);

  //intersection of the sets
  group1.retainAll(group2);
  
  group1.forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer but it also isn't suitable for a comment.

In your first case, you want the common elements from two separate sets.
This is referred to as the intersection of two sets.
The [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface declares method `retainAll()` that gives you the intersection of two sets.

In your second case, you want the *difference* between two sets.
Again the `Set` interface declares the `removeAll()` method.

However, according to the information in your question, it appears that each set contains different element types. I'm guessing that the first set contains instances of `BaseAdapter` while the second set contains instances of `EndPoint`.

So in order to use methods `retainAll()` and `removeAll()` both sets should contain the same type of element.
You can solve this by making each class - `BaseAdapter` and `EndPoint` - implement the same interface. Note that this interface need only be a marker interface, i.e. an interface that declares no methods, like [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). Also note that you don't have to use an interface from the JDK, you can define your own, for example:

```java
public interface NoMethods {
}
```

Still, in order for methods `retainAll()` and `removeAll()` to give you the correct results, you need to implement some method to compare an instance of `BaseAdapter` with an instance of `EndPoint`. For this comparison, I suggest that you use the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.

So to summarize, a skeleton for class `BaseAdapter` could be:

```java
public class BaseAdapter implements NoMethods, Comparable<NoMethods> {
}
```

Similarly for class `EndPoint`

```java
public class EndPoint implements NoMethods, Comparable<NoMethods> {
}
```

Remember to implement method `equals(Object)` in both classes.

Finally you would declare each set as

```java
Set<NoMethods> set;
```

Note that I have not verified the above, it is just a suggestion. Hence my opening remark that this is not really an answer.